# HyperSQL - unexpected token ON

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I'm trying to use HyperSQL in my Java application in the following way:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    static Connection conn;
    static Statement stat;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred while loading HSQLDB JDBC driver: " + ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:hsqldb:file:helper_db;sql.syntax_mys=true");

            stat = conn.createStatement();

            stat.executeUpdate(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table " +
                     "(" +
                        "foo TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        "bar TEXT" +
                    ");"
            );

            stat.executeUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO some_table VALUES" +
                        "('foo', 'bar') " +
                        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE some_table = VALUES" +
                        "('foo', 'bar');"
            );

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + ex.getMessage());
            return;

        }

    }
}
```

This code gives me the following output:

```
An error occurred: unexpected token: ON
```

What am I doing wrong? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But i'm using MySQL syntax (sql.syntax_mys=true) that supports ON DUPLICATE. Or is it not fully-implemented MySQL syntax? And what am i need to use? I'm only need to do smth like REPLACE INTO.

Comment: Why do you think HSQLDB supports MySQL syntax? It is a different DBMS and thus has a different syntax (which *is* documented in the manual)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think that sql.syntax_mys=true do it, no?

Comment: Did you read the description on what that does? http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#N14C22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB does not support the `ON DUPLICATE` syntax (which is clearly documente in the manual).

You need to use MERGE instead assuming that there is at least one column in your values clause that is a unique key:

```
MERGE INTO some_table ut
USING (
  VALUES
    ('foo', 'bar')
) AS md (foo_column, bar_column) ON (ut.foo_column = md.foo_column)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
     SET ut.bar_column = md.bar_column
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (foo_column, bar_column)
  VALUES (md.foo_column, md.bar_column);
```

Please check the manual for more details: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement

Answer (score 0):

The updated version of HSQL now supports `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature of MySQL.

Refer: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#coc_compatibility_mysql